# Sharepoint 2013 jquery code not working properly

Tags: sharepoint-online

1 test working  https://jsfiddle.net/rurounisena/16c5om2t/

2  tried to use on sharepoint table not working https://jsfiddle.net/rurounisena/6o5a2t48/

The point of this code is to check the date expected column and see if the date is in the past. Future dates, NaN, and if the text in the last column is 'received' ('horror' in the 1st test) and all their corresponding data is ignored. The last thing is to alert 'state + type + datediff'. So in the actual share point example there should only be 3 of them. Is there any reason this is not working in sharepoint?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sample script don't match what you need exactly, you need custom the logic per your requirement. you need jQuery knowledge to get the specific（last) column data and then compare.

For example: `j(elem).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(9)')` get the 9th td of the row.